# Postgresql to Laravel eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

Someone please teach me how to use COALESCE and TO_CHAR in laravel DB:raw()

```
SELECT MAX(COALESCE(SUBSTR("COLUMN_CODE",8),'0')) AS MAX
FROM public."TABLE_ITEM"
WHERE COALESCE(TO_CHAR("START_DATE",'YYYYMM'),TO_CHAR("RECEIVED_DATE",'YYYYMM')) = '202104'
```

Tried using DB:raw but still got error

```
selectRaw("MAX(COALESCE(SUBSTR(COLUMN_CODE,8),0)) AS MAX")
->whereRaw("COALESCE(TO_CHAR("START_DATE",'YYYYMM'),TO_CHAR("RECEIVED_DATE",'YYYYMM')) = '202104'")
```

Comment: What is your error?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't use quotes right. The is some example of how to use quotes for SQL functions in whereRaw() method:

```
->whereRaw("tv_technicals.created_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(candidates.pierce_time, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
                            AND DATE_ADD(candidates.pierce_time, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)");
```